# Where do I get the item price, total tax, and shipping cost when tracking purchases on Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics, in-app-purchase, easytracker

According to the [Google Analytics eCommerce guide for Android](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/ecommerce), I need to use the `Tracker.sendTransaction` method to track purchases.  Three pieces of information needed are the purchase price, the total tax, and the shipping price (all longs).  However, the response provided from making in-app purchases provides none of this data.

Am I missing something?  Are these pieces of information actually returned?  Where can I find them to set them?

Answer (score 1):

You can get information about all your products using the [getSkuDetails](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails)-method:

```
ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String> ();
skuList.add("premiumUpgrade");
skuList.add("gas");
Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
querySkus.putStringArrayList(“ITEM_ID_LIST”, skuList);

Bundle skuDetails = mService.getSkuDetails(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", querySkus);
```

code taken from: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryDetails

You know which product the user bought by inspecting the data returned after a purchase:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { 
   if (requestCode == 1001) {           
      int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
      String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
      String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
         try {
            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
            String sku = jo.getString("productId");
            // TODO: query getSkuDetails() and find the matching product
            alert("You have bought the " + sku + ". Excellent choice, 
               adventurer!");
          }
          catch (JSONException e) {
             alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
   }
}
```

code taken from: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#Purchase

Comment: Thank you, but the JSON response does not provide the 3 items I mentioned in the original question.